# There is no researchable topic in Riemannian Lie group and Lie algebra!

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, research

Most of my teachers say to me that there is no new researchable topic in Riemannian Lie group and Lie algebra! Is this true? Can you encounter some new works on Riemannian Lie Groups such as Milnor paper ([Curvatures of left invariant metrics on lie groups](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870876800023))?

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly there are enough research topics, motivated by Milnor's paper. Just search a bit who is citing Milnor's article. For related research see my [homepage](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/publications.html), e.g. no. $4,33,41$.

Comment: There are several topics arising from this paper. Possibly not exhaustive: (a) invariant structures on Lie groups and homogeneous spaces. This is probably the one Dietrich has in mind in his comment. (b) Riemannian geometry on Lie groups, e.g. the study of minimal surfaces therein, etc. This is far more analytic. (c) The study of large-scale geometry of Lie groups as geometric objects. This takes part in geometric group theory.